# Handling empty/invalid Mqtt Messages with Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to ingest data from Mqtt into Kafka. Unfortunately, some of those Mqtt-Messages are either empty or invalid JSON. I assume that is what leads to the following exception:

```
{
  "name": "source_mqtt_alarms",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "-redacted-:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "-redacted-:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: 
        Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:196)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:314)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:340)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:264)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\t
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\t
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\t
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\t
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\t
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n
        Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Conversion error: null value for field that is required and has no default value\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:611)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJsonWithEnvelope(JsonConverter.java:592)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.fromConnectData(JsonConverter.java:346)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:314)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)\n\t
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\t
        ... 11 more\n"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

From what I've learned so far, it looks like the incoming (empty/invalid) messages do not contain values that are declared as non-optional, which leads to the exception above.

My question would be, where is the connector taking that expectation from? It says "null value for field that is required and has no default value", but how is that field required if the schema is (I assume) created per message?

---

**Additional information:**
I am using the Lenses.io Stream Reactor Mqtt Source Connector. The configuration is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "source_mqtt_alarms",
    "config": {        
        "topics": "alarms",
        "connect.mqtt.kcql": "INSERT INTO alarms SELECT * FROM `-redacted-/+/alarms` WITHCONVERTER=`com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter`",
        "connect.mqtt.client.id": "kafka_connect_alarms",
        
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mqtt.source.MqttSourceConnector",
        
        "connect.mqtt.service.quality": 2,
        "connect.mqtt.hosts": "ssl://-redacted-:8883",
        
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.ca.cert": "/usr/share/certs/cumu.crt",
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.cert": "/usr/share/certs/mqtt.crt",
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.key": "/usr/share/certs/mqtt.pem",

        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,

        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": true,
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I just went through the logs of the Kafka Connect worker and it's giving a bit more information. Prior to the exception above, I get a lost of these:

```
[2021-05-26 08:27:19,552] ERROR Error handling message with id:0 on topic:-redacted-/alarms (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mqtt.source.MqttManager)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:430)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:427)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter$.convert(JsonSimpleConverter.scala:76)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter$.convert(JsonSimpleConverter.scala:70)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter.convert(JsonSimpleConverter.scala:37)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mqtt.source.MqttManager.messageArrived(MqttManager.scala:110)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: I don't think the JsonSimpleConverter is compatible with the schemas.enable=true field (you're getting exceptions in both classes, the first explicitly coming from a schema validation)

Comment: I'll have to test a few more things, but it seems like the JsonOptNullConverter works. I'll update once I'm sure that's why it's working (I tried a lot of things). I think I also tried all possible values for schemas.enable (and even left it out).

Comment: The default value for the schemas.enable property is true, I believe. Other than that, I'm actually not sure of all possible converters the streamreactor package has

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that messages without a payload can be easily removed with a Filter transformation and the RecordIsTombstone predicate, as follows: (last 6 lines):

```
{
    "name": "source_mqtt_alarms",
    "config": {        
        "topics": "alarms",
        "connect.mqtt.kcql": "INSERT INTO alarms SELECT * FROM `-redacted-/+/alarms` WITHCONVERTER=`com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter`",
        "connect.mqtt.client.id": "kafka_connect_alarms",
    
       "tasks.max": 1,
        "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mqtt.source.MqttSourceConnector",
    
        "connect.mqtt.service.quality": 2,
        "connect.mqtt.hosts": "ssl://-redacted-:8883",
    
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.ca.cert": "/usr/share/certs/cumu.crt",
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.cert": "/usr/share/certs/mqtt.crt",
        "connect.mqtt.ssl.key": "/usr/share/certs/mqtt.pem",

        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,

        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,

        "transforms": "Filter",
        "transforms.Filter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
        "transforms.Filter.predicate": "IsTombstone",

        "predicates": "IsTombstone",
        "predicates.IsTombstone.type": 
        "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone"
    }
}
```